# Redirect aspx in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, asp.net, redirect, 301-redirect

I had a site in ASP.NET, and now we moved it to WordPress. The pages in the .NET site have parameters in them.

I'd like to redirect the old pages to their new locations, but Apache doesn't seem to understand parameters, so when I write in .htaccess redirects like this, they don't work:

`redirect   301 /Apps/WW/Page.aspx?ws=4ed09703-8210-4492-a86a-128c1b9822b3&page=458f828d-616d-469d-8fe2-13d3c2881df3    http://s.ort.org.il/redirects/`

The solution I thought of is to create a /Apps/WW/ directory, and in it create a Page.aspx file, and redirect that to a WordPress page (called *redirects*), like this:

`redirect   301 /Apps/WW/Page.aspx  http://s.ort.org.il/redirects/`

And in the *redirects* page, in PHP, analyze the parameters and redirect via PHP.

Is that a good solution? It seems a little too complex, and I'm not a system person (I'm a web programmer), so I don't know any other solutions

Comment: If there are similarities between your asp url parameters and the urls in word press for the same articles you should be able to use apache's mod_rewrite to rewrite the url's without use the redirects page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From speaking to the WordPress support, I found out that query parameters are not supported in redirect or rewrite rules.

They confirmed that I should write a rewrite rule in .htaccess that redirects the page without the parameters to a php file, and in that file I should use php to analyze the parameters and redirect accordingly. I don't need to create a /Apps/WW/ directory, and in it to create a Page.aspx file. The reidrect doesn't need it.

They also suggested that the php file which will do the redirecting shouldn't be in WordPress, because it will not perform very well as it will load the whole WordPress environment for any of these urls. This is not needed.